# Custom Accumulator won't use Kryo Serialization for Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, kryo

For a spark streaming service I have created a custom accumulator as shown below:

```
public class CustomAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2<CustomClass, Set<CustomClass>> {

    private Set<CustomClass> invalidSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean isZero() {
        return invalidSet.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public AccumulatorV2<CustomClass, Set<CustomClass>> copy() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        invalidSet.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(CustomClass customClass) {
        invalidSet.add(customClass);

    }

    @Override
    public void merge(AccumulatorV2<CustomClass , Set<CustomClass >> accumulatorV2) {
        invalidSet.addAll(accumulatorV2.value());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<CustomClass> value() {
        return invalidSet;
    }
}
```

I have been using kryo serialization for my spark streaming job which has worked fine for broadcasting my CustomClass:

```
final Class[] serializableClasses = {CustomAccumulator.class, CustomClass.class};
    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(serializableClasses);
```

However, when a worker adds a CustomClass object to the CustomAccumulator object, the following error is thrown from the driver:

```
[task-result-getter-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 25) had a not serializable result: com.project.CustomClass
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29493 Serialization stack:
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29499   - object not serializable (class: com.project.CustomClass, value: CustomClass{id=...})
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29503   - writeObject data (class: java.util.HashSet)
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29503   - object (class java.util.HashSet, [CustomClass{id=...}])
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29504   - field (class: com.project.CustomAccumulator, name: invalidSet, type: interface java.util.Set)
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29504   - object (class com.project.CustomAccumulator, CustomAccumulator(id: 0, name: Some(Custom Accumulator), value: [CustomClass{id=...}]))
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29504   - writeExternal data
2017-12-13 11:22:34,29505   - externalizable object (class org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult, org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult@2aa7e7e1); not retrying
```

The issue is fixed when I force my CustomClass to implement Serializable. However, I'd like to stay consistent with my serialization and make the accumulator use the kryo serialization that is already registered in the spark context.  Does anyone have any idea as to how to utilize kryo for a custom spark accumulator?

Comment: Have you set the serializer to be kryo `conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")`? Also does CustomClass have a no-arg constructor?